# Flash: How to obtain values of GET variables into flash as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, get, variables

For example, I have in my page "flash.swf?SomeVariable=123"

How to get the value of "SomeVariable" GET-variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's

```
this.root.loaderInfo.parameters.SomeVariable;  //should return 123
```

Am I right?